# android set limit on editText with "date" input type

Tags: android, xml, date, android-edittext

In my app I have an `EditText` with date input type.

I want user not to set time bigger than some const time or present time. How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better option would be to use [DatePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html) with the methods `setMaxDate` and `setMinDate`